# blue and white AlertDialog in honeycomb

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to create an AlertDialog like this :

[image]

I know that a blue and white view like this can be made by writing a custom XML file. My question is that is there a built in theme in Android (like Holo) which can be applied to get this effect.

I want to do it in an application being built for Honeycomb. The screenshot is from an Ice Cream Sandwhich emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution close to this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

This produces a dialog similar to the one above, except that the title is not in blue color (instead, it is in black color).